# Jtable options sorting

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-jtable

I can't sort options, and i don't understand why.
The code is easy

```
    cliente: {
title: 'Cliente',

options: 'FattureActions.php?action=ragionisociali',
optionsSorting: 'text',
width: '20%'
},
```

on php page

```
//Get records for ragione_sociale
else if($_GET["action"] == "ragionisociali")
{
//Get records from database
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT ragione_sociale, id FROM clienti");

//Add all records to an array
$righe = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
$tmp = array();
$tmp['DisplayText'] = $row['ragione_sociale'];
$tmp['Value'] = $row['id'];
$righe[] = $tmp;
}

//Return result to jTable

$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Options'] = $righe;
print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```

Question 1:
Why I can't use the order sytanx in sql like $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT ragione_sociale, id FROM clienti order by ragione_sociale"); ??
Question 2:
optionsSorting: 'text', doesn't have effect

What's wrong?
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Try latest version. older version have not optionsSorting.  In case of query, You can write ORDER BY ragione_sociale DESC.

Comment: Thanks Ravi Hirani, I have updated at last version. Now everything is ok